# How to send JSON array data from one JS function to Another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am calling a JS function from another and sending JSON array data. While sending the data to 2nd function I am getting value as undefined/null. How to send JSON array data from one JS function to Another ?

**Function: 1**

```
$(function createJsonArray() {

            var categories =  [
                    'Jan',
                    'Feb',
                    'Mar',
                    'Apr',
                    'May',
                    'Jun',
                    'Jul',
                    'Aug',
                    'Sep',
                    'Oct',
                    'Nov',
                    'Dec'
                ];

            var confidence = [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4];

            var jsonArray = {
                issueData: []
            };

            jsonArray.issueData.push({
                "categories": categories,
                "confidence": confidence
            });
            //alert('categories: ' + jsonArray.issueData[0].categories);


            // calling function-2
            createGraph(JSON.stringify(jsonArray));
        });
```

**Function: 2**

```
$(function createGraph(graphData) {
            var jsonArray = $.parseJSON(graphData);
            alert('jsonArray: ' + jsonArray);
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: jsonArray.issueData[0].categories,
                    crosshair: true
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                        '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
                    footerFormat: '</table>',
                    shared: true,
                    useHTML: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        pointPadding: 0.2,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Tokyo',
                    data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

                }]
            });
        });
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLkUz/67/) link

Comment: There is no mention of `value` in your code..?

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/hLkUz/69/ Your createGraph method is not being called from createJsonArray method. It is being as the script is being loaded.

Comment: why do you wrap them both in `$(function` ?

Comment: there is no need  to convert string your json data. You send directly, if you cant you can determine it on your window object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLkUz/70/)

You need to invoke the `createJSONArray()` method and get rid of the jquery call of `$(function functionName)`, instead just define a simple method.